# jquery get text from link instead of list

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the display text of a link  and ended up using this tag which doesn't appear jquery-ish enough..any alternatives?

for the following HTML

```
<div id="c-100001" class="cal-list-row cal-slug-item selected"><a href="" class="cal-name">Link Text</a></div>
```

the following jquery seems very inelegant though it works

```
string = $('#' + c_key).find('a').contents()[0].data
// string should be plain "Link Text"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question so that anybody else searching for the right answer will find it.
Kudos to all for trying to help but this was a problem being caused by a specific jquery plugin which was modifying the default jquery behavior

basically the jquery-template plugin contributed by Stan Lemon (https://bitbucket.org/stanlemon/jquery-templates/) is changing jquery behavior so that the .text() seems to return a list of objects not the text from the first item.

Reporting the same to the author, though this plugin seems defunct ...wil probably migrate to what the jquery UI team develops here(http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/37898666/Template)

Reporting all this in the hope that it help somebody else as well :)

Comment: Ok, nice you find out how to resolve your issue, but stating on the real question (your question) here you have a bunch of correct answers, and I think at least someone deserves an upvote from you or at least an accept (green 'V') correct answer. Cause some answers **ARE** correct - no matter what you have discovered.

Answer (score 1):

[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/amugap/edit#preview)

```
var string = $('#' + c_key).find('a').text();
```

Comment: I am not getting this result as per your demo on my page with jquery 1.7.2..any ideas on why that might be?

Comment: Sure! wrap our code into a ready function: `$(function(){ /*CODE HERE*/ });`

Comment: still returns an object not the text itself

Comment: @eskhool please tell me how looks your `c_key` , what is returned?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var string = $('#' + c_key).find('a').html();
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with my HTML I get this in the console [ <a href class=​"cal-name">Link Data​</a>​ ] its a list of elements ..I'm using jquery 1.7.2 and some plugins

Comment: You can try than $('#' + c_key).find('.cal-name').html(); with anchor class name.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all links within a container using

```
var links = ("a", $("#containerElement"));
```

This will get you a list of `<a ..` elements.

Then you can iterate over them or simply take the first and call `.text()` on it if i't still wrapped as a jQuery element or if you retrieve the pure HTML tag you can simply use `.innerHTML`.

Example:

```
var linkText = $("a", $("#myContainer"))[0].innerHTML;
```

or

```
var linkText = $("a", $("#main")).first().text();
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with my HTML I get this in the console
[
<a href class=​"cal-name">​Principal's Appointments​</a>​
]

its a list of elements ..I'm using jquery 1.7.2 and some plugins but this is basic jquery